# ISA Server Publishing Rule to Allow Connections From a Particular WAN IP/Subnet

Tags: firewall, isa-server

I am looking to publish access to a particular server behind a Microsoft ISA server and limit access to a particular Public Server range. For instance, I only want to allow RDP access to the exchange server behind the ISA from the public IP address of my office. I'm pretty familiar with ISA server publishing rules, just having difficulty figuring out how to constrict the access to a particular IP range.

Comment: Which version of ISA?

Comment: Forefront TMG 6.0.6417.100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Toolbox in the ISA 2006 Manager.  Expand Network Objects, right click on Address Ranges.  Enter in your IP range. You may have to create multiple Address Ranges.  When you create a rule in the Firewall Policy, uses these Address Ranges on the From tab.  You can also add multiple items on this tab.